# A proof using Menelaus' theorem and Ceva's theorem.

Tags: geometry

[image]

Need to show (d)

I have followed the problem and came up with the expression of the expression of the individual line segments:

from (b): $AB = \frac{CX}{RX} \cdot RB \cdot \frac{CQ}{QA} 
$

$CQ = QA \cdot \frac{RB}{AB} \cdot \frac{XC}{RX}$

$RB = \frac{CQ}{QA} \cdot AB \cdot \frac{RX}{XC}$

$QA = CQ \cdot \frac{AR}{RB} \cdot \frac{RX}{XC}$

and from (c): after applying Ceva's theorem

$\frac{AR}{RB} \cdot \frac{BP}{PC} \cdot \frac{CQ}{QA} = 1$

which leads to the explicit expression for PC and BP.

When I attempted (d), the workload is quite a lot when I tried to combine the explicit expressions of each line segments, and it wasn't clear to me how it would yield the result.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the Angle Bisector Theorem.

$\displaystyle \frac{BP}{PC}=\frac{\textrm{area of }\triangle BAP}{\textrm{area of }\triangle CAP}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(AB)(AP)\sin\angle BAP}{\frac{1}{2}(AC)(AP)\sin\angle CAP}=\frac{AB}{AC}$